# Collision detection not working. Circle and Square not detecting collision after calculation

Tags: java, processing

This is the method for detecting the collision. The satellite is a circle and the ship is a rectangle.

```
boolean hitSatellite(Ship ship, Satellite satellite) {
  float left = ship.getXPos();
  float right = ship.getXPos() + ship.getWidth();
  float top = ship.getYPos();
  float bottom = ship.getYPos() + ship.getHeight();
  float satelliteLeft = abs(satellite.getXPos() - satellite.getDiameter()/2);
  float satelliteRight = abs(satellite.getXPos() + satellite.getDiameter()/2);
  float satelliteTop = abs(satellite.getYPos() + satellite.getDiameter()/2);
  float satelliteBottom = abs(satellite.getYPos() - satellite.getDiameter()/2);
   if (!(left > satelliteRight || right < satelliteLeft || top < satelliteBottom || bottom > satelliteTop)) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

This is the method being called in the draw method.

```
boolean collection = hitSatellite(ship, satellite);
  if (collection) {
    println("You have collected" + count + " Satellite");
    satellite.Start();
  }
  score++;
}
```

Comment: This is written as if both hitboxes were rectangles, is that right or were you supposed to deal the circle as a real circle?

Comment: Check [this](http://jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/circle-rect.php), it has many combinations and will be really useful, specially if you then would like to do your satellites with random polygonal shapes.